# Redirect Rule to Url Rewrite .NET Core

Tags: redirect, .net-core, url-rewriting

I am implementing AddRewrite rule in Startup.cs like this:

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRewrite(@"^UserLogin/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)", "User/UserLogin?param1=$1&param2=$2", skipRemainingRules: true)
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

This works well and url is being rewritten correctly when visited: UserLogin/param1value/param2value

Now I would like to redirect old, original urls and I tried this:

```
    var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect(@"^User/UserLogin?param1=([0-9]+)&param2=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)", "UserLogin/$1/$2", (int)HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
            .AddRewrite(@"^UserLogin/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)", "User/UserLogin?param1=$1&param2=$2", skipRemainingRules: true)
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

However I cannot get this to work and I cannot get the new url to work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

First the `?` in your regular expression needs to be escaped as `\?`, since ? in regular expression means match 0 or 1 times.

But even that won't help since according to documentation of `AddRedirect` method what it does is

> Redirect the request if the regex matches the HttpContext's PathString

Since Path string does not include query string, it won't match. And this is Evident if you look at [the implementation source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Rewrite/src/RedirectRule.cs)

Unfortunately the implementation is internal, so you can't make a rule that inherits from RedirectRule, but since the implementation is open source, you can copy the implementation and create your own redirect rule that matches both the url and query string.